# Information loss from clustering

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, repeated-measures, panel-data, survey

I'm looking for a method of assessing the information loss associated with being forced to use a GLM mixed model instead of a standard GLM.

We conducted a survey investigating behaviors of pregnant women and young mothers. We decided that we would obtain two samples at different times of the year to assess seasonality in some of the estimates.  Our survey vendor was supposed to ensure that no one was able to take the survey twice, but we have learned that there were people who slipped through and took it twice; around 40% in the second wave took it in the first wave.  Therefore, we accidentally have longitudinal data.  What I'm looking for is this: **How do I quantify the loss in information or power due to the repeated measures?**

The only way I can think of is to run a model with and without repeated measures (the second being, I assume the responses are independent even though they aren't), and show how the estimates and confidence intervals differ.  I'm wondering if there are other ways to quantify what we have lost based on this error.  I recognize my question is on the vague side, but I'm looking for advice on how to frame this issue.

Comment: Your question is interesting, as repeated measures studies are generally more powered than non-repeated measures.  ¿For what specific parameter are you concerned about not being able to detect a difference?

Comment: The final outcome is a proportion of women who have used a specific drug.  I'm not interested so much in whether one woman has increased in likelihood of use, but whether use amongst this population has changed over time (a population level measurement).